# How to make a button accept Enter as Submit button in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a page with some text boxes in it and a button

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I want this button to be pressed.

Comment: For the button's click event to be fired when you press enter, the button has to be selected. You can call the button's Select() method to do this.

Comment: @Gareth Not quite true, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `AcceptButton` property on the form to the button you want pressed on enter.

Similarly, if you want something for escape, that's the `CancelButton` property.

Comment: your answer doesn't work, in windows 8 apps this property is not available

Comment: You're using .net aren't you? What object are you using for the form.

Answer (score 1):

XAML

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Height="30" Width="200" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
    <Button Content="Login" Click="btnLogin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        DoLogin();
    }
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoLogin();
}

private void DoLogin()
{
    tbStatus.Text = "Login Done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer to this, you have to use the event "Keypress" on the last text box / or all textboxes, inside it write :

```
if (e.key == virtualkey.enter)
{
    // do submit functions
}
```